# Pushing to checked out branch and executing git hook after

Tags: git, githooks, git-push

I have been setting up some Git hooks on my remote GitHub and it seems like I ran into a dilemma.

I have a hook that calls a Makefile to deploy my web application in my Git repository and that hook executes post-update when a push to master is detected. However, pushing to the checked out branch of a remote repository is no good to do and otherwise fails. It is rather recommended to have a bare repository when pushing. However, if the repository is bare then my Git hooks cannot be executed properly since all the files are essentially blobs.

What are my options for fixing this issue? I can always push a branch and merge it into master (have a post-merge hook instead of a post-update hook) but that would entail having to SSH into my server to do the merge and defies the whole point of the hook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case is the reason allowing the push is configurable.

Comment: I could have a hook that checks out another branch before updating but checking out a branch means changing root directory files and that would entail deleting (or moving) the binary of a running program.

Comment: What I mean is, you want to do a checkout-on-push hook.  Whether you do that to the repository's configured worktree and index or have the hook supply one is immaterial.  Configure `receive.denycurrentbranch false` and do `git reset --hard` in the hook, you're done. That's simplest.

Comment: I am not comfortable doing a "git reset --hard" every push and moreover, that seems like a hack. I am going to try and reset my origin to a bare repo and have the bare repo cloned locally into a work directory and deployed through the post-update hook. That seems like the sanest option to me.

Comment: Whatever you do will have exactly the effect on some checkout that `git reset --hard` will have on this one, or else it will be wrong.